# Indeterminate terms in a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If a series has some kind of indeterminacy in any of its terms, is that enough to conclude that the series diverges? For example

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(-\frac{1}{ln(k)}\right)^k$$

at $k = 1$, we have an indeterminacy.

I know that if this series starts at $k=2$, it converges. So, my doubt is about the correctness of declaring that the series starting with $k = 1$ diverges by the presence of indeterminacy, or converges because from $k = 2$, the series converges.

Comment: You just can't start from $k=1$ because that expression isn't defined. Instead you start from $k=2$. This even before trying to investigate any convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases, you cannot say that the series converges or diverges. Both words have a precise meaning.

**This series is just not defined.**